# How To Return Last Insert ID From NodeJS Sequelize .save() Method

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Given this example,

```
// insert the conversation into the lookup
const LOOKUP = new PrivateMessageLookup;

LOOKUP.communicator1 = communicator1;
LOOKUP.communicator2 = communicator2;

LOOKUP.save();
```

Where `PrivateMessageLookup` is the Model

The `LOOKUP.save()` inserts the record correctly, but how can I get the insert ID of that record?

I can not find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the [`Model.create()`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-create) function it will return a Model Instance that has the ID set. This is a short cut for building a new object, specifying that it is a new record, and then saving it.

```js
// create a new instance from the model
const lookup = await Lookup.create({ communicator1, communicator2 });
// the ID will populate
console.log(lookup.id);
```

Longhand version:

```js
// build the record, specify it is new
const lookup = Lookup.build({ communicator1, communicator2 }, { isNewRecord: true });
// save
await lookup.save();
// the ID will populate
console.log(lookup.id);
```